# Beamer Lecture: reference title of lecture in the course

Tags: beamer, cross-referencing, labels

Example:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\begin{document}

\lecture{lecture 1}{week 1}
\begin{frame}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
see Lecture \ref{week 1}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

This yields

[image: excerpt of slide]

yet it would be nice to have something like "see Lecture 'lecture 1'", so printing the title of the lecture with label "week 1".

Any ideas how to implement this? Ideally, this should be compatible with cross-referencing and includeonlylecture as explained at [reference to equation from other lecture in class beamer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/210287/reference-to-equation-from-other-lecture-in-class-beamer)

**Icing on the cake** would be the following: having a macro \lectureref{label}, where label is a \label{}-label on a frame within the scope of a \lecture{}-lecture.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is actually fairly easily done. You can already manually set a `\label` for a `\lecture` and use that for cross-referencing. We can easily insert one at every `\lecture` using `\AtBeginLecture`. In order to allow referencing the name, we have to set `\@currentlabelname` first. (I chose to use the short lecture title for this, but you can the the long form if you prefer.) Then, we can use the usual commands `\ref` and `\nameref`.

It is generally advisable to name all your labels with a prefix denoting their type. I chose the `lec:` prefix here. So you will have to use e.g. the label `week-1` in `beamer`'s native commands but `lec:week-1` when cross referencing.

```latex
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{csquotes}

\makeatletter
  \AtBeginLecture{%
    \edef\@currentlabelname{\beamer@shortlecturename}%
    \label{lec:\beamer@currentlecturelabel}%
  }
\makeatother

\includeonlylecture{week-2}

\begin{document}

\lecture[short week~1 title]{very long and clumsy week~1 title}{week-1}
\begin{frame}
  a frame
\end{frame}

\lecture{week~2 title}{week-2}
\begin{frame}
  see lecture~\ref{lec:week-1}, which is called~\enquote{\nameref{lec:week-1}}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image: MWE output]

Comment: I'll think some more about your icing on the cake, though that is a bit more involved.

Comment: Great and thanks. Regarding this xr-solution from the other question, I just was surprised that (it seems, if I do not mix things up) I can avoid using this package and the solution with externaldocument when I use frame-labels after the frame I want to reference. Yet a \lectureref-command would be here very handy.